# System.getProperty("user.dir") giving me eclipse pah when i called in stepDefinitions file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber

Following is my simple stepDefinitions class

```
package com.samp.stepDefinitions;

import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.*;

public class StepDefinitions 
{
    @Given("^when navigate to URL \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void when_navigate_to_URL(String arg1) throws Throwable 
    {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    }
}
```

Following is my runner class:

```
package com.samp.runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
            format={"pretty"},
            features={"src/test/java/features"}
            )
    public class CucumberRunner 
    {

    }
```

In my output i am seeing eclipse path. How can i see my maven project path

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem where i configured my feature file at project level.

For ex: if my project is at \ProjectName
if it is maven project we have src\test\java etc... dont keep your feature files anywhere here.

Keep your feature files at project level like 
\ProjectName\features.

If we keep like this, and configure tags, we can run these features from any runner classes.